# How to create json object in vbscript file?

Tags: json, vbscript

How to create JSON object in .vbs file?

I have tried this:

```
set json = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

But this object is not supporting `json.AddStringAt` property. How to create JSON object that supports the `json.AddStringAt`?

My sample file is

```
Dim fso, outFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile("output.json", True)

set json = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

index = -1

success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"Title","Pan's Labyrinth")
success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"Director","Guillermo del Toro")
success = json.AddStringAt(-1,"Original_Title","El laberinto del fauno")
success = json.AddIntAt(-1,"Year_Released",2006)

json.EmitCompact = 0
outFile.WriteLine(json.Emit())

outFile.Close
```

Comment: If you take a [code sample](https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/create_json.asp) that uses a particular COM object you can't just replace that object with an arbitrary other COM object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a library that has the method that you are looking for.

```
set json = CreateObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonObject")
```

https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatJsonObjectRef.html

Comment: I have tried this but got this error. ActiveX component can't create object: 'Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonObject'

Comment: Did you download and install their ActiveX library?

Comment: https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/create_json.asp

Right above nearly the same example that you posted is the download link.

Comment: Installed ActiveX library and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For 32 bit

```
set json = CreateObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonObject")
```

For 64bit

```
set json = CreateObject64("Chilkat_9_5_0.JsonObject")
```